# Terminology: "entries" of a tuple

Tags: terminology

Is there a conventional term for the "entries" of a tuple? Possible candidates that come to mind are "entry," "term," and "element," but I don't know if one is more common than the others.

Comment: What about `component`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a **tuple** consists of two or more **components**.